# Filter data sets with LINQ by year of a date

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my LINQ Statement:

```
var query = from s in ctx.location
    join b in ctx.order on s.locationID
    equals b.ID
    join e in ctx.offerdata on b.OrderID
    equals e.OrderID

    where e.delDate.Value.Year == 2013

   orderby e.identity_no
   select new Order
   {
...

   };

  return query.ToList();
```

My delDate is a ?DateTime, and for example it looks like 2013-05-15 14:10:00 (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss).
But I want to receive all data sets e.g. for the year 2013. (or any other year I choose).

But the *where e.delDate.Value.Year*  statement do not offer a .Contains Method, so how can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "and for example it looks like 2013-05-15 14:10:00 (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss)" - no, it doesn't; it is actually a number; it only looks like that because you are forcing it to be displayed, and some layer is formatting it; that isn't the date, though - in the same way that the string `"123"` is not the number `123` - it is just a text representation of it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does your existing query work?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here would be to construct a range, i.e.

```
var start = new DateTime(2013,1,1), end = new DateTime(2014,1,1);
...
    where e.delDate.Value >= start && e.delDate.Value < end
```

You *could* also use the date-part utilities, but that then depends on what the LINQ provider supports; pretty much **any** provider will support a basic range.